# Executar função javascript se condição for verdadeiro

Tags: javascript

Boa noite.

Eu tenho um botão que ao ser clicado, chama a função abaixo:

```
$('#sa-success').click(function () {
   swal({
      title: 'Good job!',
      text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lorem erat, tincidunt vitae ipsum et, pellentesque maximus enim. Mauris eleifend ex semper, lobortis purus sed, pharetra felis',
      type: 'success',
      buttonsStyling: false,
      confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary'
   });
});
```

Porém eu queria que essa função fosse executada se ocorresse determinada condição em meu IF. Exemplo:

```
if(teste == true){
   $('#sa-success').click(function () {
      swal({
         title: 'Good job!',
         text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lorem erat, tincidunt vitae ipsum et, pellentesque maximus enim. Mauris eleifend ex semper, lobortis purus sed, pharetra felis',
         type: 'success',
         buttonsStyling: false,
         confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary'
      });
   });
}
```

É possivel?

Comment: Por quê não coloca o `if` dentro do evento `click`?

Comment: Você quer ativar o `click` em `#sa-success` apenas se teste for true é isso? se sim, funciona.

Comment: Essa função não é executada... ela fica silenciosa até que o evento ocorra. Ficou meio sem sentido a pergunta. Faz como foi sugerido, coloca o if dentro.

Comment: Isso, a função não é executada, mas dessa forma se não passa no `if` ela não é atachada ao elemento. Mas, faz com o `if` dentro, fica mais fácil de entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo as sugestão do @AndersonCarlosWoss faz parecido:

```
  $('#sa-success').click(function () {
      if (teste !== true) {
        return;
      }
      swal({
         title: 'Good job!',
         text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lorem erat, tincidunt vitae ipsum et, pellentesque maximus enim. Mauris eleifend ex semper, lobortis purus sed, pharetra felis',
         type: 'success',
         buttonsStyling: false,
         confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary'
      });
   });
```